# scrollTo not working complicated view

Tags: android, android-asynctask, scrollview, scrollto

I have a layout that is  like this

RelativeLayout

```
ScrollView 
 RelativeLayout
       TextView
       ListView
       .....
       ExpandableTextView
       Button

        ....
        other Listviews
        ....
        Adview
```

....

ListViews element are loaded by AsyncTask.
On button click expandableTextView expands or collapses.

Problem is that when i  collapse  expandableTextView,the view is not moving up. I've tried scrollTo method,but is not working...

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              if(...) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
                            sv.scrollTo(0,descTxt.getTop());;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{                     
                }
            }
        });
```

I've tried implement above in `onCreate` and then in `onPostExecute` of `asynctask` but nothing happens. Whats going wrong? Thanks!!

Is it possible that is not working because of asynctask or because of that scrollview changes size dynamically according to elements?

Comment: where  is descTxt in your layout

Comment: descTxt is the expandableTextView ....

Comment: problem is your descTxt.getTop() is not giving right value maybe it is giving  zero

Comment: i have also tried scrollTo(0,0) for going to top of scrollview...but it didn't also worked

Comment: you try to give some hard coded value like scrollTo(0,50) and see if it is working or not

Comment: i've just tried it.nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I hope is work for you.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
        sv.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
    }
}, 200);
```